# How to reset file explorer layout?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

How can I reset a File Explorer window's layout, such components' size in the windows as side bar, search bar and other to default?

Answer (score 2):

1. Delete individual folder saved views by deleting these two registry keys:

```
HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU
HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags
```

2. Delete custom templates created by **Apply to Folders** by deleting:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams\Defaults
```

3. Delete the Navigation Pane state by deleting:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Modules\NavPane
```

Comment: It wasn't helpful, I try it and the layout stay as before, such width of the navigation pane in left side.